# Resolve a promise after CountUp.js is finished counting

Tags: javascript

let's say we want to animate a count up from 10 to 100, using [CountUp.js](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/) we should do something like this:

The question is how can I resolve a promise after the counting has finished.

```js
createMainCountUp(); // initiate once
function createMainCountUp(){
  const div = document.createElement("div");  
  div.id = "percentCounterTarget";   
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

promisedFunc(); // this is a function I want

async function promisedFunc() {

  console.log('counting has started...');

  await Counting(); // I want to resolve this function when counting has finished
  
  console.log('counting has finished!');

}

// here is the main function to start counting
function Counting(){
dial = new CountUp('percentCounterTarget', 10, 100, 4, 5);
dial.start(); 

//easing dial function
function CountUp(target, startVal, endVal, decimals, duration, options) {
  var self = this;
  // default options
  self.options = {
    useEasing: true, // toggle easing
    useGrouping: true, // 1,000,000 vs 1000000
    separator: ',', // character to use as a separator
    decimal: '.', // character to use as a decimal
    easingFn: fastEase, //normalEase, //slowEase, // optional custom easing function
    formattingFn: formatNumber, // optional custom formatting function, default is formatNumber above
    prefix: '', // optional text before the result
    suffix: '', // optional text after the result
    numerals: [] // optionally pass an array of custom numerals for 0-9
  };

  // extend default options with passed options object
  if (options && typeof options === 'object') {
    for (var key in self.options) {
      if (options.hasOwnProperty(key) && options[key] !== null) {
        self.options[key] = options[key];
      }
    }
  }

  if (self.options.separator === '') {
    self.options.useGrouping = false;
  } else {
    // ensure the separator is a string (formatNumber assumes this)
    self.options.separator = '' + self.options.separator;
  }

  // make sure requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame are defined
  // polyfill for browsers without native support
  // by Opera engineer Erik Möller
  var lastTime = 0;
  var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz', 'ms', 'o'];
  for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }
  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
        callback(currTime + timeToCall);
      }, timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };
  }
  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  }

  function formatNumber(num) {
    var neg = (num < 0),
      x, x1, x2, x3, i, len;
    num = Math.abs(num).toFixed(self.decimals);
    num += '';
    x = num.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? self.options.decimal + x[1] : '';
    if (self.options.useGrouping) {
      x3 = '';
      for (i = 0, len = x1.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i !== 0 && ((i % 3) === 0)) {
          x3 = self.options.separator + x3;
        }
        x3 = x1[len - i - 1] + x3;
      }
      x1 = x3;
    }
    // optional numeral substitution
    if (self.options.numerals.length) {
      x1 = x1.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w) {
        return self.options.numerals[+w];
      })
      x2 = x2.replace(/[0-9]/g, function(w) {
        return self.options.numerals[+w];
      })
    }
    return (neg ? '-' : '') + self.options.prefix + x1 + x2 + self.options.suffix;
  }
  //Ease functions
  function fastEase(t, b, c, d) {
    return c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / d) + 1) * 1024 / 1023 + b;
  }

  function normalEase(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts = (t /= d) * t;
    var tc = ts * t;
    return b + c * (tc * ts + -5 * ts * ts + 10 * tc + -10 * ts + 5 * t);
  }

    function slowEase(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts = (t /= d) * t;
    var tc = ts * t;
    return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
  }

  function ensureNumber(n) {
    return (typeof n === 'number' && !isNaN(n));
  }

  self.initialize = function() {
    if (self.initialized) return true;

    self.error = '';
    self.d = (typeof target === 'string') ? document.getElementById(target) : target;
    if (!self.d) {
      self.error = '[CountUp] target is null or undefined'
      return false;
    }
    self.startVal = Number(startVal);
    self.endVal = Number(endVal);
    // error checks
    if (ensureNumber(self.startVal) && ensureNumber(self.endVal)) {
      self.decimals = Math.max(0, decimals || 0);
      self.dec = Math.pow(10, self.decimals);
      self.duration = Number(duration) * 1000 || 2000;
      self.countDown = (self.startVal > self.endVal);
      self.frameVal = self.startVal;
      self.initialized = true;
      return true;
    } else {
      self.error = '[CountUp] startVal (' + startVal + ') or endVal (' + endVal + ') is not a number';
      return false;
    }
  };

  // Print value to target
  self.printValue = function(value) {
    var result = self.options.formattingFn(value);
    console.log(value);
  };

  self.count = function(timestamp) {

    if (!self.startTime) {
      self.startTime = timestamp;
    }

    self.timestamp = timestamp;
    var progress = timestamp - self.startTime;
    self.remaining = self.duration - progress;

    // to ease or not to ease
    if (self.options.useEasing) {
      if (self.countDown) {
        self.frameVal = self.startVal - self.options.easingFn(progress, 0, self.startVal - self.endVal, self.duration);
      } else {
        self.frameVal = self.options.easingFn(progress, self.startVal, self.endVal - self.startVal, self.duration);
      }
    } else {
      if (self.countDown) {
        self.frameVal = self.startVal - ((self.startVal - self.endVal) * (progress / self.duration));
      } else {
        self.frameVal = self.startVal + (self.endVal - self.startVal) * (progress / self.duration);
      }
    }

    // don't go past endVal since progress can exceed duration in the last frame
    if (self.countDown) {
      self.frameVal = (self.frameVal < self.endVal) ? self.endVal : self.frameVal;
    } else {
      self.frameVal = (self.frameVal > self.endVal) ? self.endVal : self.frameVal;
    }

    // decimal
    self.frameVal = Math.round(self.frameVal * self.dec) / self.dec;

    // format and print value
    self.printValue(self.frameVal);

    // whether to continue
    if (progress < self.duration) {
      self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
    } else {
      if (self.callback) self.callback();
    }
  };
  // start your animation
  self.start = function(callback) {
    if (!self.initialize()) return;
    self.callback = callback;
    self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
  };

  // pass a new endVal and start animation
  self.update = function(newEndVal) {
    if (!self.initialize()) return;
    newEndVal = Number(newEndVal);
    if (!ensureNumber(newEndVal)) {
      self.error = '[CountUp] update() - new endVal is not a number: ' + newEndVal;
      return;
    }
    self.error = '';
    if (newEndVal === self.frameVal) return;
    cancelAnimationFrame(self.rAF);
    self.paused = false;
    delete self.startTime;
    self.startVal = self.frameVal;
    self.endVal = newEndVal;
    self.countDown = (self.startVal > self.endVal);
    self.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(self.count);
  };

  // format startVal on initialization
  if (self.initialize()) self.printValue(self.startVal);
}
}
```

**Note:** the StackOverflow snippet not showing the logs correctly. the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `CountUp.start()` can take [a callback function](https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js#:%7E:text=with%20optional%20callback), you could create and return a Promise that calls the `resolve` function once the countdown is finished.

```js
function counting() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const dial = new CountUp(...);
    dial.start(resolve);
  });
}
```

**Edit:** Once the countdown is finished CountUp will call the callback function that you pass into `.start()`. You can see this in the copy of `CountUp.js` you posted in your snippet - at the comment "whether to continue" in `self.count`, it calls the callback function once the countdown is finished progressing. We can utilize this in a promise by calling `resolve` once the countdown is complete.